Error in connecting Azure SignalR service with Azure Function
I'm getting the following error when I try to register signalr services in my startup.
"func: Invalid host services. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: The following service registrations did not match the expected services:
Invalid] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.HeartBeat, Microsoft.Azure.SignalR, Version=1.27.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60."
I use the following code
 private IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    
     var temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureSignalRConnectionString");
     services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(temp);
     return services;
 }```

Any suggestion to fix this ? 



I need a solution to fix this 


I have tried the same in In-Process Azure function and got the same error.
Connection to the SignalR can be established by defining the environment variable named AzureSignalRConnectionString.
Refer the solution provided by @zetawars.
The SignalR Azure function would by default pick the connection from a fixed location AzureSignalRConnectionString in local.settings.json.
Function Code:
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,"get", "post")] HttpRequest req,
    [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "HubValue")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
{
    return connectionInfo;
}

But this can be achieved AddAzureSignalR in .NET 8.0 Isolated process using the below code:
Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureSignalRConnectionString");
        });
        services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "<SignalR_connection_string>"
  }
}

Output:
Functions:

        negotiate: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7201/api/negotiate

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-09-20T12:31:05.809Z] Executing 'Functions.negotiate' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=eca3f826-7265-4a6c-bcb2-89d6e329a9de)
[2024-09-20T12:31:06.538Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-09-20T12:31:06.604Z] SignalR Connection URL = 'https://kpsignalr.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=hubvalue'
[2024-09-20T12:31:06.707Z] Executed 'Functions.negotiate' (Succeeded, Id=eca3f826-7265-4a6c-bcb2-89d6e329a9de, Duration=929ms)


